# Properly add custom property to Socket object type-safely

Tags: typescript, socket.io

Following [the official Socket.IO guide](https://socket.io/get-started/private-messaging-part-1/), I attempt to assign a `username` property to the `socket` object

```
socket.username = username;
```

TypeScript raises the error

```
Property 'username' does not exist on type 
'Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, any>'.ts(2339)
```

Wanting to stay true to the philosophy of TypeScript- what is the proper, type-safe way to extend custom properties on socket objects, other than creating a sub-type to use in place of `Socket`?

Or should I instead regard that section of the official guide as bad code and change the way I approach tracking usernames?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a sub-type, you can extend the original Socket interface:

```
// First import the original Socket
import { Socket } from 'socket.io';

// Extend the interface
declare module 'socket.io' {
    interface Socket {
        username: string;
    }
}

// Finally the new attribute can be used in addition to the rest of the original Socket attributes and methods.
io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.username} connected with ID ${socket.id}`);
}
```